# NSString as a resources in Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to simply declare static `NSString` as defined int identifier ? I want to do something like in C++ `#define MY_SIMPLE_ID 4`.

EDIT:
Where should I declare this? In C++ I have global access to resource file with it. Is there a way to do that in Objective-C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not using :

```
#define MY_STRING @"MyString"
```

Comment: But which class i should declare this macro? In visual c++ you have a global access to defined resources. Is there a something like this in objective-c?

Comment: Just make an H file with all your defines and include that file in your precompiled header (.pch file).  That's what I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go into your Project or Target **Build Settings**, and add to **Preprocessor Macros** or **Preprocessor Macros Not Used In Precompiled Headers**.  See [Xcode Preprocessor Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245288/1318452) for the distinction between these two options.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use this in a separate class with only static values:

in the constants.h file:

```
extern int const MY_SIMPLE_ID;
extern NSString const MY_SIMPLE_STRING;
```

in the constants.m file:

```
int const MY_SIMPLE_ID = 4;
NSString const MY_SIMPLE_STRING = @"thestring";
```

With this it's a global static value in the entire application.