# How can PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER be used as NSErrorDomain for app errors?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, compile-time-constant

How can the product bundle identifier of an OS X app be used for an error domain? Are there any pitfalls of using it so?

It doesn't seem to be defined as a macro; I tried:

```
NSErrorDomain BSDomain = PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER;
```

This results in an error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems build setting variables are available on the command line, though not within source files. For any such variable, a [preprocessor macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367368/90527) (see also ["Add preprocessor macro to a target in xcode 6"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26928622/90527)) can be defined manually [based on the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242817/90527). The macro and setting can be given different names, but likely giving them the same name will make more sense.

In this case, the value should start with an "@" and be surrounded by escaped double-quotes, so they're part of the macro and will be included when the macro is substituted. If either is left off, the macro value won't be a valid NSString constant (required for use as an NSErrorDomain value). The macro should be added to all configurations (Debug, Release, and any user-defined).

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=@\"$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)\"
```

If the product bundle ID will also be used in other ways, the macro could be defined with the raw value (`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`) with the appropriate sytax introduced at the usage sites:

```
NSErrorDomain BSDomain = @"PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER";
```